# Set data in javascript file via backend c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the following situation.
I want to show a (donut) graph with data in my web page.
I'm getting the data from my database in my backend of my webpage (ASP.NET/C#).

I'm using a standalone javascript file ('graph.js') for the graph:

```
//Donut Chart
var donut = new Morris.Donut({
element: 'sales-chart',
resize: true,
colors: ["#3c8dbc", "#f56954", "#00a65a"],
data: [
  { label: "**DATA**", value: **10** },
  {label: "**DATA**", value: **30**},
  {label: "**DATA**", value: **20**}
],
hideHover: 'auto'
});
```

Is there a good way of putting the data in the javascript file? (Changing the **DATA** variables)

I know it's possible to put the javascript in script elements on my aspx page, and getting my data there:

```
var DataNumber = <%=DataNumber%>;
```

And giving this data in the backend:

```
 private String _dataNumber = String.Empty;
 protected string DataNumber {
     get {
         return this._dataNumber ;
     }
     set {
         this._dataNumber = value;
     }
 }
```

but that's not what i'm looking for.
I realy want to use an standalone file for this.

Comment: You can execute an Ajax-Get request to load data from a external source, for example [Web-API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Answer (score 2):

I'm more into `cshtml` files, but you could render a serialized list containing your variables, in an hidden div in your `ASPX` file :

```
<div class="hidden" id="myData" data-data="<%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData)%>"></div>
```

Then, you could get this data from within your `javascript` code:

```
$(function() {
  var data = $("#myData").data('data');
  var donut = new Morris.Donut( /* do something with data */);
})
```

I'm using newtonsoft `JSON.NET` to serialize, and `JQuery` to parse json data.

Another solution is to make an `Ajax` call to fetch your data.

**Edit:**

Here is an example with something similar I've done in `ASP.NET`:

File `donut.aspx.cs`:

```
// ...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // edit the following line to suit your needs
    var list = new List<Data>(your_data_as_list);
    donut.Attributes.Add("data-donut", list)
}
// ...
```

File `donut.aspx`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/morris.js"></script>

<!-- create a component that will be managed by C#
<div runat="server" id="donut"></div>

<!-- this will execute once the page is loaded -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        // use <%= donut.ClientID %> to get the generated Id from ASP.NET
        var donutData= $("#<%= donut.ClientID %>").data("donut");
        var donut = new Morris.Donut( /* do something with donutData*/);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Assuming that you don't want to retrieve data later after page is loaded using ajax, you can put your data in global object with you razor syntax, before your standalone script is executed like this:

```
window.mydata = <%=DataNumber%>;
```

Just keep number of global objects to a minimum. Use single root for all globals. Like this:

```
window.myGlobals.mydata = <%=DataNumber%>;
```

And later access it from wherever you want.

If you want to avoid globals completely, there is several ways you could do that, but all of them include rendering you data to your page.

For example, you could put data attributes in your script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-mydata="<%=DataNumber%>" src="mymodule"></script>
```

And in script, just access it trough `$(document.currentScript).data("mydata)...`

But, beware that you don't loose it during bundling process...

Comment: How do I acces the data in the javascript file?
Something like this:   "var test = $(document.currentScript).data("mydata");"
Because if I do, and I do an  "alert(test);" afterwords, I'm getting "undefined"

Comment: Yes, something like that should work. Look it up in debugger. Did you set data attribute correctly? Some older browser may have an issue with currentScript. Look it up in you console debugger what does it say

Comment: I did it another way:

    <script 
        type='text/javascript' 
        data-id="MyUniqueName" 
        data-token="<%=DataNumber%>"  
        src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/dist/js/pages/dashboard2.js")%>' ></script>

and 

     var token = document
    .querySelector('script[data-id="MyUniqueName"][data-token]')
    .getAttribute('data-token');